# Find lists in list of lists whose length is equal to certain value

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

I'm using python 2.7 and want to find list in list of lists whose length is equal to certain value

```
EX: [['abc,'orange,'NYC'],['def','apple','NYC','USA'],['xyz','california'],['qwe','mango','USA']......]]
```

Outcome : List not equal to length 3

```
['def','apple','NYC','USA'],['xyz','california']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use a list comprehension:

```
A = [['abc','orange','NYC'],['def','apple','NYC','USA'],
     ['xyz','california'],['qwe','mango','USA']]

res = [i for i in A if len(i) != 3]

print(res)

[['def', 'apple', 'NYC', 'USA'], ['xyz', 'california']]
```

Comment: thanks, it worked!!